# Python strategy Pattern with Abstract class: error AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute

Tags: python, runtime-error, abstract-class, strategy-pattern

I am trying to code a Strategy pattern in Python using Abstract class. I wish to use a concrete method (the `__assembly_band`) wrote inside the abstrect class in oder to factorize a procedure for all concrete strategies.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class TestSpectralStrategy(ABC):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __assembly_band(self, par: int):
        return int * 10

    @abstractmethod
    def algorithm(self, size: int):
        pass


class TestConcreteSpectralStrategy(TestSpectralStrategy):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def algorithm(self, size: int):
        return super().__assembly_band(size)
```

When I run the code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test= TestConcreteSpectralStrategy()
    test.algorithm(10)
```

I got this message

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '_TestConcreteSpectralStrategy__assembly_band'
```

Comment: The point of `__name_mangled` leading-double-underscore attributes is to _prevent_ them with clashing attributes in the subclasses, by making them less accessible. In this case you probably just want `_assembly_band`. See e.g. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables.

Comment: totally agreed with @jonrsharpe. Inside the function '__assembly_band' you're doing int*10 - int is a type you can't just multiply it with 10. I guess you're trying to do par * 10 instead.